# Interaction between JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 3 JFrames where the first one opens the other two. These two JFrames are then supposed to interact with each other. One of them is going to show a picture and the other one has JSliders to change certain values of that picture etc.

How can I implement an ActionListener for my JSliders that will update the picture in the other JFrame? Creating an object of that other JFrame will call its constructor but I don't want to open that JFrame a second time. Maybe my approach is just completely wrong?

A simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class JFrame1 extends JFrame {
...
}
    public JFrame1 () { // Constructor
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //when button is pressed
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFrame2 obj2 = new JFrame2(); // open JFrame2
        JFrame3 obj3 = new JFrame3(); // open JFrame3
        }
    });
    }

public class JFrame2 extends JFrame {
...
}
    public JFrame2 () { //Constructor
    ...
    ActionListener for JSliders from JFrame3 to update values whenever they're changed??
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon (image)); //display image
    }

public class JFrame3 extends JFrame{
...
private JSlider slider1;
private JSlider slider2;
}

    public JFrame3 () { //Constructor
    ...
    some JSlider settings
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another private member of type `JFrame3` in frame 2 and frame 3, like this:

```
public class JFrame2 extends JFrame {
    public JFrame2(JFrame3 frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        // Now you add your listeners, you have access to the sliders of your JFrame3
        ...
    }
    private JFrame3 frame;
    ...
}
```

Now, in the `JFrame3` class, you need to make all the `JSliders` public, so that they are accessible from `JFrame2` else the compiler will complain.

After that in `JFrame1` constructor pass the instance of `JFrame3` to the constructor of the `JFrame2` like this:

```
public JFrame1 () { // Constructor
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //when button is pressed
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame3 obj3 = new JFrame3(); // open JFrame3
        JFrame2 obj2 = new JFrame2(obj3); // open JFrame2
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I've shifted the order of constructing the `JFrame`s, So that I could pass the `obj3` to the constructor of `JFrame2`

Comment: Nit picking: It's a bad idea to pass the entire component to another class, because now I can all sorts of nasty things to it that I'm to suppose to ;)

Comment: Thank you! For now this answer really helps me but I'll keep your answer in mind as well, Madprogrammer :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer for educational purposes, what nasty things can you do if you knew you were passing the entire component to another class?? and how??

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Hmm, `removeAll`  - basically you can do what ever you want, which could upset the operations of the program - replace components for example, which other parts of the program where relying on; upset the event chain by adding your own listeners which modify state the rest the of the program relied on - and yes, I’ve had team mates do this to me 

Comment: must have been frustrating, haha xD

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to become farmiluar with the [model-view-controller](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) design pattern.

One of things you want to do is reduce the amount of responsibility that any one class has.

In your case, you have one window which is displaying an image and another which is displaying controls (although I'd consider using a single window to display both, the concept remains the same).

Neither class really has responsibility for "changing" the image based on the inputs, instead, that should actually fall to another class - a model.

This would take input from the "controls" window, modify it's state and generate events to which interested parties could respond (aka the [observer pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)).

In this way, you can change the implementation of the model without adversely affecting the other classes which rely on it (this relies on another concept - [Code to interface not implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/)), as they aren't reliant on the implement, but the contract defined y the interface(s) of the model.

When you establish the "controls" and "image" windows, you would also pass both of them the same instance of the "model", through this, both windows will be able to communicate - to what extent will be defined by the contract of the model, but I would imagine it would be mostly one way (controls view -> model -> image view)